# Retrieving a Type's leaf interfaces

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, hierarchy

The [System.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) class provides a [GetInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx)() method that "gets all the interfaces implemented or inherited by the current Type". 
The problem is that "The GetInterfaces method does not return interfaces in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which interfaces are returned, because that order varies". 
In my case, however, I need to isolate and expose (via WCF) only the leaf interfaces of the interface hierarchy, that is interfaces that are not inherited by other interfaces in that hierarchy. For example, consider the following hierarchy

```
interface IA { }
interface IB : IA { }
interface IC : IB { }
interface ID : IB { }
interface IE : IA { }
class Foo : IC, IE {}
```

Foo's leaf interfaces are IC and IE, whereas GetInterfaces() will return all 5 interfaces (IA..IE).
A [FindInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.findinterfaces.aspx)() method is also provided, allowing you to filter the aforementioned interfaces using a predicate of your choice.

My current implementation is given below. It is O(n^2) where n is the number of interfaces the type implements. I was wondering if there was a more elgant and/or efficient way of doing it.

```
    private Type[] GetLeafInterfaces(Type type)
    {
        return type.FindInterfaces((candidateIfc, allIfcs) =>
        {
            foreach (Type ifc in (Type[])allIfcs)
            {
                if (candidateIfc != ifc && candidateIfc.IsAssignableFrom(ifc))
                    return false;    
            }
            return true;
        }
        ,type.GetInterfaces());
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you will find a simple solution to this. Your problem is that in the end, `Foo` actually implements *all the interfaces*, regardless of their internal inheritance hierarchy. If you examine `Foo` using Ildasm or some similar tool this becomes evident. Consider the following code:

```
interface IFirst { }
interface ISecond : IFirst { }
class Concrete : ISecond { }
```

The resulting IL code (dumped from Ildasm):

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit MyNamespace.Concrete
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
       implements MyNamespace.ISecond,
                  MyNamespace.IFirst
{
  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // Code size       7 (0x7)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  ret
  } // end of method Concrete::.ctor

} // end of class MyNamespace.Concrete
```

As you can see, on this level there is no difference in the relation between `Concrete` and the two interfaces.

Comment: Thanks!
Perhaps my GetLeafInterfaces() function could be of use to someone in the future, then